# Calculating a 2d distance matrix from a Google DistanceMatrix response in Java

Tags: java, google-distancematrix-api, distance-matrix

I am trying to solve the Travelling Salesman Problem and Vehicle routing problem with the Google Or tools library, in the tutorial found [here](https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/tsp), they use a distance Matrix `whose i, j` entry is the distance from location i to location j in miles, where the locations are given in the order below:

1. New York 1. Los Angeles 2. Chicago 3. Minneapolis 4. Denver 5. Dallas 6. Seattle 7. Boston 8. San Francisco 9. St. Louis 10. Houston 11. Phoenix 12. Salt Lake City

And their matrix distance looks like:

```
  public final long[][] distanceMatrix = {
      {0, 2451, 713, 1018, 1631, 1374, 2408, 213, 2571, 875, 1420, 2145, 1972},
      {2451, 0, 1745, 1524, 831, 1240, 959, 2596, 403, 1589, 1374, 357, 579},
      {713, 1745, 0, 355, 920, 803, 1737, 851, 1858, 262, 940, 1453, 1260},
      {1018, 1524, 355, 0, 700, 862, 1395, 1123, 1584, 466, 1056, 1280, 987},
      {1631, 831, 920, 700, 0, 663, 1021, 1769, 949, 796, 879, 586, 371},
      {1374, 1240, 803, 862, 663, 0, 1681, 1551, 1765, 547, 225, 887, 999},
      {2408, 959, 1737, 1395, 1021, 1681, 0, 2493, 678, 1724, 1891, 1114, 701},
      {213, 2596, 851, 1123, 1769, 1551, 2493, 0, 2699, 1038, 1605, 2300, 2099},
      {2571, 403, 1858, 1584, 949, 1765, 678, 2699, 0, 1744, 1645, 653, 600},
      {875, 1589, 262, 466, 796, 547, 1724, 1038, 1744, 0, 679, 1272, 1162},
      {1420, 1374, 940, 1056, 879, 225, 1891, 1605, 1645, 679, 0, 1017, 1200},
      {2145, 357, 1453, 1280, 586, 887, 1114, 2300, 653, 1272, 1017, 0, 504},
      {1972, 579, 1260, 987, 371, 999, 701, 2099, 600, 1162, 1200, 504, 0},
  };
```

They further provide a [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/vrp#distance_matrix_api) on how to create a distance matrix dynamically except it is in `Python` and I am a not very good in it, I am using `Java`.

In my Java `implementation` I am using the `Java Client` and my code looks like

```
private static long[][] buildDistanceMatrix(int matrixSize, DistanceMatrix distanceMatrix) {
        long[][] matrix = new long[matrixSize][matrixSize];
        for (int i = 0; i < distanceMatrix.rows.length; i++) {
            DistanceMatrixElement[] elements = distanceMatrix.rows[i].elements;
            for (int j = 0; j < elements.length; j++) {
                    matrix[i][j] = elements[j].distance.inMeters;
            }
        }
        return matrix;
    }


    public static void getDistanceMatrix(List<LatLng> origins, List<LatLng> destinations){
        GeoApiContext context = new GeoApiContext.Builder()
                .apiKey(GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY)
                .build();
        DistanceMatrixApiRequest distanceMatrixApiRequest = DistanceMatrixApi.newRequest(context)
                .mode(TravelMode.DRIVING)
                .trafficModel(TrafficModel.BEST_GUESS)
                .departureTime(Instant.now().atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant())
                .destinations(destinations.toArray(new LatLng[destinations.size()]))
                .origins(origins.toArray(new LatLng[origins.size()]));


        distanceMatrixApiRequest.setCallback(new PendingResult.Callback<DistanceMatrix>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(DistanceMatrix distanceMatrix) {

                long[][] matrix = buildDistanceMatrix(destinations.size(), distanceMatrix);
                System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(matrix));

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
                throwable.printStackTrace();

            }
        });
    }
```

And the result looks like

`[[10196, 6647, 4881], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]`

I do not understand how the matrix was made in the `python code`, can someone help me formulate it?

My DistanceMatrix response looks like

````
"destinationAddresses": [
    "Central St, Lusaka, Zambia",
    "Unnamed Road, Lusaka, Zambia",
    "Jacaranda Rd, Lusaka, Zambia"
],
"originAddresses": [
    "1940 - 3 Munthaka Cl, Lusaka, Zambia"
],
"rows": [
    {
        "elements": [
            {
                "distance": {
                    "humanReadable": "10.2 km",
                    "inMeters": 10193
                },
                "duration": {
                    "humanReadable": "23 mins",
                    "inSeconds": 1352
                },
                "durationInTraffic": {
                    "humanReadable": "26 mins",
                    "inSeconds": 1549
                },
                "status": "OK"
            },
            {
                "distance": {
                    "humanReadable": "6.6 km",
                    "inMeters": 6647
                },
                "duration": {
                    "humanReadable": "13 mins",
                    "inSeconds": 779
                },
                "durationInTraffic": {
                    "humanReadable": "14 mins",
                    "inSeconds": 839
                },
                "status": "OK"
            },
            {
                "distance": {
                    "humanReadable": "4.9 km",
                    "inMeters": 4881
                },
                "duration": {
                    "humanReadable": "9 mins",
                    "inSeconds": 516
                },
                "durationInTraffic": {
                    "humanReadable": "9 mins",
                    "inSeconds": 538
                },
                "status": "OK"
            }
        ]
    }
]

}```
````

Comment: @Anbry Lungu have found any solution please let me know.

Comment: @RajKumar yes I did. Check my answer, if you need further assistance do not hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did resolve this. I used the `Euclidean distance formular` to get a distance matrix

```
/// @brief Compute Euclidean distance matrix from locations array.
/// @details It uses an array of locations and computes
/// the Euclidean distance between any two locations.
private static long[][] computeEuclideanDistanceMatrix(long[][] locations) {
    // Calculate distance matrix using Euclidean distance.
    long[][] distanceMatrix = new long[locations.length][locations.length];
    for (int fromNode = 0; fromNode < locations.length; ++fromNode) {
        for (int toNode = 0; toNode < locations.length; ++toNode) {
            if (fromNode == toNode) {
                distanceMatrix[fromNode][toNode] = 0;
            } else {
                distanceMatrix[fromNode][toNode] =
                        (long) Math.hypot(locations[toNode][0] - locations[fromNode][0],
                                locations[toNode][1] - locations[fromNode][1]);
            }
        }
    }
    return distanceMatrix;
}
```

The full solution looks like

```
public static Assignment findWithVehicleRoutingProblem(List<LatLng> destinations, int numOfVehicles) {
    long[][] distanceMatrix = RoutUtils.computeEuclideanDistanceMatrix(RoutUtils.scaleCoordinatesForEuclidean(destinations));
    RoutingIndexManager manager = new RoutingIndexManager(distanceMatrix.length, numOfVehicles, 0);

    RoutingModel routing = new RoutingModel(manager);
    final int transitCallbackIndex = routing.registerTransitCallback((long fromIndex, long toIndex) -> {
        int fromNode = manager.indexToNode(fromIndex);
        int toNode = manager.indexToNode(toIndex);
        return distanceMatrix[fromNode][toNode];
    });

    routing.setArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(transitCallbackIndex);

    routing.addDimension(transitCallbackIndex, 0, 3000,
            true, 
            "Distance");
    RoutingDimension distanceDimension = routing.getMutableDimension("Distance");
    distanceDimension.setGlobalSpanCostCoefficient(100);

    RoutingSearchParameters searchParameters = main.defaultRoutingSearchParameters()
            .toBuilder()
            .setFirstSolutionStrategy(FirstSolutionStrategy.Value.PATH_CHEAPEST_ARC)
            .build();

    return routing.solveWithParameters(searchParameters);
}
```

Where `findWithVehicleRoutingProblem` takes in an `arraylist` of `destinations`. `LatLng` is a simple class  that looks like

```
public class LatLng  {
public double lat;
public double lng;
}
```

And the `scaleCoordinatesForEuclidean` method

```
private static final long DISTANCE_MATRIX_SCALE_FACTOR = 100000000000L;
   private static long[][] scaleCoordinatesForEuclidean(List<LatLng> destinations) {
    long[][] locations = new long[destinations.size()][destinations.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < destinations.size(); i++) {
        long[] coordinate = {(long) (destinations.get(i).lat * DISTANCE_MATRIX_SCALE_FACTOR), (long) (destinations.get(i).lng * DISTANCE_MATRIX_SCALE_FACTOR)};
        locations[i] = coordinate;
    }
    return locations;
}
```

Comment: could you please help me out on what paramerts which i need to for this method computeEuclideanDistanceMatrix(..) @Astonio

Comment: The params are really easy, so given 2 places on a map, each place is identified by its coordinates, a coordinate includes a latitude and longtitude. so the locations array is just a multi-dimensional array of locations.

Comment: So in my original question, that would be coordinates for New York 1. Los Angeles 2. Chicago 3. Minneapolis 4. Denver 5. Dallas 6. Seattle 7. Boston 8. San Francisco 9. St. Louis 10. Houston 11. Phoenix 12. and Salt Lake City

Comment: you mean we need to prepare an array with latitude and longitude?

Comment: Here latitude and longitude are in double but we need to pass variable as long array, if we convert double to long then result will to 2 digits number like below 
22.272504, 96.607590 to 22,96 will it be ok?

Comment: if possible can you please help me out with your example what you did so that i can crack this @Astonio

Comment: @RajKumar exactly. Uhhm. I am updating my answer.

Comment: could you please update your answer please... :) wating for your answer.

Comment: if possible could you please send us this method code RoutUtils.scaleCoordinatesForEuclidean(destinations) @Astonio

Comment: @RajKumar I have added it. Double vote my answer :D

Comment: Thank you @Astonio and i would like to know what all scenarios you have worked on Google OR Tools Like Capacity constraint & Time window constraint etc...may i know..